# Swift + Facebook SDK + AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am basically sure that this won't work, because Swift does not have AppDelegate.m

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  
  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;
}
```

I can't seem to find on Facebook.com the Swift version. Can this be made to work?

Comment: `UIApplicationDelegate` is mandatory for any iOS app. There is a swift version for your code if you create a new project with Xcode.

Comment: @scorpiozj i got that part

Comment: This documentation now has both SWIFT and Objective-C versions of code:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#app-delegate